# comparing two lists, if the entry from list one differs by x amount of characters to entry from list 2 replace list one entry with list two entry

Tags: python, regex, list, replace

I have two lists, I'll just put a rough example below as the lists are over 50k entries

```
`location_names = ["London", "Uk", "Manchaster", "The City", "Jersey", "Hampshire", "East Midlands"]
spell_list = ["London", "Gateshead", "Manchester", "Dorking", "London", "Northampton", "East London"]`
```

I want to compare these lists each entries with its corresponding entry on the other list, and if they differ by less x amount of characters replace the entry in location_names with its corresponding entry in spell_list.

Some of these are spelling corrections and others replaced the word with whole different words so I only wanted to replace the ones with spelling errors, if that makes sense.

I think I need to use regex to dictate it but I'm not sure how to word it.

## edit :

there has been a useful answer however, i think it is trying to compare 1 entry from the first list with all entries from the second list.

eg.

```
location_names[0],spell_list[0],spell_list[1],spell_list[2]
location_names[1],spell_list[0],spell_list[1],spell_list[2]
location_names[2],spell_list[0],spell_list[1],spell_list[2]
ect.
```

I only want it to compare 1 entry from 1 list with 1 entry from the second list

eg.

```
location_names[0], spell_list[0]
location_names[1], spell_list[1]
location_names[2], spell_list[2]
```

any help would be great thanks

Comment: Please do mention what you tried and what didn't work out for you.

Comment: @BethHooper, Have a look into lib https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy use it to find the ratio of the match between string & replace based on that.

Comment: I used fuzzywuzzy to get spell_list however, however it gave some really wild matches because of the list I gave it to initially compare to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SequenceMatcher will do the job perfectly.. You can try this..

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

location_names = ["London", "Uk", "Manchaster", "The City", "Jersey", 
"Hampshire", "East Midlands"]
spell_list = ["London", "Gateshead", "Manchester", "Dorking", "London", 
"Northampton", "East London"]

def match_words(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

for index, (location, spell) in enumerate(zip(location_names, spell_list)):
    if match_words(location, spell) >= 0.9:
        location_names[index] = spell

print(location_names)
```

*OutPut:['London', 'Uk', 'Manchester', 'The City', 'Jersey', 'Hampshire', 'East Midlands']*

It Replaces the word from location_names if word matches 90% or more..

Comment: I've got the progress bar working and it says the ETA for running this code on my full list is 11 hours..... this seems like a really long time, is it supposed to take that long and is there a more efficient method?

Comment: you can use **ProcessPoolExecutor**.. that will reduce time drastically depending on your computer's processing power..

Comment: I think what it is happening is that it is comparing 1 location_names entry with all entries in location_spelling.... but i only want to compare 1 location_names entry with 1 location_spelling entry....

for example: list1[0], list2[0] | 
list1[1], list2[1] | 
list1[2], list2[2]
etc

if that makes sense

Comment: Understood..Check the edited code now, now it should not take that much time, Still u can use `ProcessPoolExecutor` to reduce runtime..